# How do I know which C++ source files include a specific h header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am studying a big C++ project and find a critical header file. I want to find all those .cpp files which include this header file to know the header file's influence scope. However I cannot find a simple way (several clicks or commands) to achieve this via vscode. Is there any trick can get this done? preferably using vscode.

Example, say we have source code files **a.cpp, b.cpp, c.cpp**..., and a header file **foo.h**, how do I know which source code file include this foo.h without opening them and check one by one?

Comment: Chage that header's name and check the compilation errors

Comment: VS Code is not a C++ IDE, so you shouldn't expect much from it. I believe Visual Studio has this functionality.

Comment: Multi-file search for `#include "foo.h"` will find the direct inclusions.

Comment: @molbdnilo Basically yes, but potentially needs to include `#include <foo.h>` as well... Maybe a regex (if searching by is available): `#\s*include\s*[<"]foo.h[>"]` which should cover strange spacing some people apply as well.

Comment: @WaisKamal Eh, it essentially is, with the right plugins. The distinction between code editors and IDEs was never that meaningful, and is becoming ever less so. The only meaningful distinction is whether a given application supports a given feature. VS Code's C++ mode happens to (currently!) not support this particular feature.

Comment: `git grep <header>` ?

Comment: just multi file search for `foo.h`, you get a few false positives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Edit->Find in Files" option inside VSCode for the header file you are looking for. The search result will give you the desired answer.